# How can I call form function in html?

Tags: 7, forms

I have requirement in that I want to show a dropdown values. So to achieve this I created a form function with `select` type and returning the form. I want to display it in a html page. Here is what I have tried:

```
function cart_confirmation_form($form, &$formstate){

  $opt = array('Hi','Bye'); 
  $form['dropdown'] = array(
    '#title' => 'somethinfg',
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $opt,
  );
  return $form;
}
   function testing(){
     $message .= '<div class="popup-related-tabs" style="float: left;" >' . cart_confirmation_form($form, $formstate) . '</div>';
      $message .= '<div class="popup-related-titles" style="padding:15px;" id="popup-related-block">'.$form_message.'</div>';
    drupal_set_message('<div class="message-inner" style="padding:15px;">' . $message . '</div>' );

}
```

This is not working, It says array to string conversion, form and formstate is undefined something like this. I know this is not correct way please suggest me the correct way to print values in dropdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming testing() is a page callback, you want this:

```
function testing()
{
  $form = drupal_get_form('cart_confirmation_form')
  $output = '<div class="popup-related-tabs" style="float: left;" >' . render($form) . '</div>';

  return $output;
}
```

Though personally I'd built it as a render array:

```
function testing()
{
  $page = array
  (
    '#prefix' => '<div class="popup-related-tabs" style="float: left;" >',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    'form' => drupal_get_form('cart_confirmation_form')
  );

  return $page;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answer also true but you can also do very easily using drupal_render like this

`function testing()
{
  $output = drupal_render(drupal_get_form('cart_confirmation_form'));
  return $output;
}`

Comment: Note that calling drupal_render() around drupal_get_form() will throw a PHP warning. The value passed to drupal_render() is supposed to be a variable, not the output of a function, as the value passed to drupal_render() is a reference. This is why I declared $form first in my answer, to prevent this PHP warning.